# How do you sort list of strings in batch?

Tags: string, sorting, batch-file

Hi i have a script that searches for certain directories based on a string provided by the user, he then presents the directories meeting the user.s inout and offers to cd to them.

```
@ECHO off

setlocal enableextensions
:start
set scriptname=%0%
set PAUSE_ON_ERROR=yes

rem #
rem ######   SECTION TO CUSTOMIZE   #####
rem #

rem #
rem # This is the list of directories where instances of TECSYS iTopia installed under 
rem # JBoss are located.
rem #

set dir_to_search_in=C: C:\TecsysDev\iTopiaControlPanel\trunk

rem #
rem ######   END SECTION TO CUSTOMIZE   #####
rem #

set argNb=0
for %%x in (%*) do Set /A argNb+=1
if %argNb% GTR 1 (
    goto :showUsage
) else if %argNb% == 0 (
    set ENV_NAME=*
) else (
    set ENV_NAME=*%~1*
)


:MainBlock
set scriptname=%0%
cd /d %~dp0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`cd`) do set scriptdir=%%D

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`cd`) do set CURRENT_DIR=%%D
cd "%scriptdir%"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`cd`) do set JBOSS_DIR=%%D
set JBOSS_DIR=%JBOSS_DIR%\..\..\..\..\..
cd "%JBOSS_DIR%"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`cd`) do set JBOSS_DIR=%%D
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"

rem Make sure that we have the findstr utility installed.

set findstr_found=
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`echo x ^| findstr x 2^>nul`) do set findstr_found=%%f
if "X%findstr_found%" == "X" (
   echo The findstr utility is not found.
   goto pauseforError
)

call :getJbossVersion

rem prepare the list of special JBoss environments to exclude

if /i "%JBOSS_VERSION%" lss "5" (
    set env_to_exclude=all default minimal
) else if /i "%JBOSS_VERSION%" lss "6" (
    set env_to_exclude=all default minimal standard web
) else (
    set env_to_exclude=all default minimal jbossweb-standalone standard
)
rem find the environment directories
for  %%f in (%dir_to_search_in%) do ( 
    for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /ad "%%~f\jboss*"') do (
        if exist "%%f\%%G\server\%ENV_NAME%" (
            for /f "delims=" %%H in ('dir /b /ad "%%~f\%%~G\server\%ENV_NAME%"') do (
                call :concat %%~f\%%~G\server\%%~H
            )
        )
    )
)
if "X%environment_home_list%" == "X" (
    echo Invalid %1 environment requested.
    goto :pauseforError
)
rem display the folders

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem checking if a unique instance of the environment exists
Set Count=0
for %%t in (%environment_home_list%) do (
    Set /A Count+=1
)
if %count% == 1 (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%d in ("%environment_home_list%") do (
        set chosenEnv=%%d
        goto :cdToEnv
    )
)

:chooseEnvironment

Set Count=1
echo.
echo Please choose an environment:
echo.
echo 0^) Exit


for %%z in (%env_home_list%) do (
    echo !Count!^) %%z
    Set /A Count+=1
)

rem reading user input
SET /P userChoice=
set /a Test=userChoice
if !Test! EQU 0 (
  if not !userChoice! EQU 0 (
    echo Please enter a valid number
    goto :chooseEnvironment
  )
)
rem checking if the user wants to exit
if %userChoice% EQU 0 (
    goto :END
)

Set /A Count-=1

rem making sure the input is valid
if %userChoice% LSS 1 (
    echo Please enter a valid choice
    goto :chooseEnvironment
)
if %userChoice% GTR %count% (
        echo Please enter a valid choice
        goto :chooseEnvironment
    )
rem matching the user input with the right element from the environment list
for /f "tokens=%userChoice% delims= " %%d in ("%environment_home_list%") do (
    set chosenEnv=%%d
)
:cdToEnv
rem taking the environment name to change the prompt
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`dir /b %chosenEnv%*`) do set chosenEnvName=%%D

rem setting the right path to cd to.
set chosenEnvHome=%chosenEnv%\deploy\%chosenEnvName%.ear
if not exist %chosenEnvHome% (
    set chosenEnvHome=%chosenEnv%\deploy\%chosenEnvName%.war
)
if not exist %chosenEnvHome% (
    set chosenEnvHome=%chosenEnv%
)
set prompt=%chosenEnvName%^>

cmd /k cd /d %chosenEnvHome%
goto :End

:concat

rem defining our list of apps installed excluding special jboss folders
set is_env_to_exclude=
for  %%L in (%env_to_exclude%) do (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%U in (`echo %1 ^| findstr %%L`) do (
        set is_env_to_exclude=yes               
    )
)
if  "X%is_env_to_exclude%" == "X" (
    set environment_home_list=%1 %environment_home_list%
    set env_home_list=%~n1 %env_home_list%
)
goto :eof

:getJbossVersion

for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%v in (`echo. ^| %JBOSS_DIR%\bin\run.bat -V ^| ^ 
                                   findstr "JBoss" ^| findstr /i /v "BootStrap"`) do (
   set JBOSS_VERSION=%%v
)

goto :EOF

:showUsage

echo Usage:  tish [environment]
   echo                  ^|
   echo                  +--- installed environment

:pauseforError
if "%PAUSE_ON_ERROR%" == "yes" pause
:End
```

My only problem is that i want the folders placed in env_home_list to be displayed alphabatically, icannot do the sort directly in the dir command, because i want to order alphabetically all the folder found and not group them by their parent folder. And i insist that i am not using a file here but only a list.

Comment: Your code is .. difficult to read. Could you please cut the story somewhat.

Comment: Ok let's say i have this list list= b c d, i want to sort it and diplay a b c, how do i do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the fact that Batch environment variables are automatically keept in sorted order by their names, so you need to insert *the value* of the variable inside *the name* of the variable. I suggest you to do that using the standard *array* naming convention and insert the value as subscript, inside the brackets:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set list=b c a

rem Separate list elements into an array, use X as a dummy value for array elements
for %%a in (%list%) do (
   set elem[%%a]=X
)

rem Process the elements in sorted order:
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set elem[') do echo %%a
```

Note that this method eliminate duplicated elements and keeps just the last value. If this is a problem, you need to also insert a counter after the value (inside the brackets).

Comment: always the same, I love it :T  .